# Extend 2 Classes PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have 3 classes (3 files):

```
a.class.php
b.class.php
c.class.php
```

I want to extend class a and b in the class c (file 3):

How I could do that? I want to use both class functions of a + b in my new class C

Comment: See my answer [to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314875/is-a-general-class-necessary-for-a-site-php-site/1314996#1314996)

Comment: you can use function __call()
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php

Comment: try function __call()
answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no **multiple inheritance** in PHP. So you can't do that.

Try using composition and re-arranging your class structure.

Answer (score 8):

You are asking for [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance), which is not supported by php. You should have a look at [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of achieving this in PHP using mixins. See this http://www.phpdeveloper.org/news/6139 for example. However I would probably try to find a different way of designing your code so you don't have to use it.

Otherwise PHP 5.4 will bring Traits which will natively support what you want: http://simas.posterous.com/new-to-php-54-traits

Answer (score -4):

class a

class b extends a

class c extends b

done.

Answer (score -4):

Class c extends a implements interface

Done